# Please tell me how can I find all the values in Oracle database if I don't know the specific schema\table\column?

Tags: sql, oracle

Please tell me how can I find all the values in Oracle database if I don't know the specific schema\table\column?

I am writing technical documentation and, for example, I want to know in which table and in which column is the value "Cat". How can i do this? A python loop over all columns and tables takes a very long time....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, *anything* will take a long time if you want to scan all tables and all columns (unless it's a tiny schema as Scott's).

Anyway: you'll need dynamic SQL. Here's an example: I'm searching through all `CHAR`-like datatype columns in my own schema (line #8), looking for `KING` (line #15):

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_str  VARCHAR2 (500);
  3     l_cnt  NUMBER := 0;
  4  BEGIN
  5     FOR cur_r IN (SELECT u.table_name, u.column_name
  6                     FROM user_tab_columns u JOIN user_tables t
  7                       ON u.table_name = t.table_name
  8                    WHERE u.data_type LIKE '%CHAR%')
  9     LOOP
 10        l_str :=
 11              'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '
 12           || cur_r.table_name
 13           || ' WHERE '
 14           || cur_r.column_name
 15           || ' like (''%KING%'')';
 16
 17        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (l_str)
 18           INTO l_cnt;
 19
 20        IF l_cnt > 0
 21        THEN
 22           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_cnt || ' : ' || cur_r.table_name);
 23        END IF;
 24     END LOOP;
 25  END;
 26  /
1 : TABLE22
1 : EMP

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

The result says that `KING` appears in two tables (`TABLE22` and `EMP`), once in each of them.

Comment: _Implicit_, comma separated join... in 2022?!?

Comment: Ah, @jarlh, that's a copy/paste of my script that ages back in ... who knows when. But yes, it still works :) Fixed, thank you!